# Is it possible for a voltage multiplier to be used to provide both positive and negative voltage?

Tags: polarity, reverse-polarity, voltage-doubler

What I was wondering is it is possible to use a single voltage multiplier to provide a negative and positive voltage.  Referring to this voltage doubler circuit, if you connect a capacitor to the top right node, and an ac source to that capacitor, can it produce dc voltage with the reverse polarity? I think it looks like it would because the diodes would be in the opposite polarity relative to the capacitor. 
[image]

Comment: Recognize that adding a "-Vout" multiplier to a "+Vout" multiplier will load the AC source - requiring more current (to charge all those capacitors, and to provide DC current to any load on +Vout, -Vout). The extra load may reduce the magnitude of Vout somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you connect a capacitor to the top right node, and an ac source to
> that capacitor, can it produce dc voltage with the reverse polarity? I
> think it looks like it would because the diodes would be in the
> opposite polarity relative to the capacitor.

If you mean this: -

[image]

Then yes but you'll still need another set of diodes and capacitors to keep your positive voltage. If this is not what you meant then I suggest you draw a picture of what you mean.